# JButton requires two clicks after getting enabled in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to build a JFrame with four manual input **JTextFields: description, hours, minutes, ID**
and two **JButtons: Submit and Reset**

I need to disable the "Submit" button until all text fields have some data. To achieve this, I have used the DocumentListener and that is working fine, that is, initially the "Submit" button is disabled and gets enabled only when all text fields have some input.

**PROBLEM:** After *"Submit"* button is enabled, I need to hit the submit button twice to get the actual action trigger (probably first time is to restore focus after getting enabled, second time to do actual work). This issue does not happen with the "Reset" button.

**TRIED AND DIDN'T WORK:** I tried restoring focus using `submit.requestFocusInWindow()` and it brought focus to the "Submit" button but the last modified text field lost focus and I had to click it again to restore focus on that field.

Please assist. I am quite new to StackOverflow, so kindly don't close the thread.

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();
JPanel descPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel timeWorkedPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel iDPanel = new JPanel();

titlePanel.add(title);
mainPanel.add(titlePanel);

descPanel.add(desc);
mainPanel.add(descPanel);

timeWorkedPanel.add(hour);
timeWorkedPanel.add(minute);
mainPanel.add(timeWorkedPanel);

iDPanel.add(iD);
mainPanel.add(iDPanel);

JTextArea reqList = new JTextArea();
reqList.setLineWrap(false);
reqList.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane reqListScroll = new JScrollPane (reqList);
reqListScroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
reqListScroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
reqListScroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
reqListScroll.setColumnHeaderView(new JLabel("               REQUEST                           CREATED                       TIME WORKED"));
mainPanel.add(reqListScroll);

List<JTextField> textFieldList = new ArrayList<>();
textFieldList.add(desc);
textFieldList.add(hour);
textFieldList.add(minute);
textFieldList.add(csiID);

JButton submit = new JButton("SUBMIT");
JButton reset = new JButton("RESET");

buttonPanel.add(submit);
buttonPanel.add(reset);
mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
mainPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(20)); // a spacer


JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
mainFrame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
mainFrame.setSize(new Dimension(500,600));
mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
mainFrame.setVisible(true);

submit.setEnabled(false);

DocumentListener docListener = new DocumentListener() {

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        changedUpdate(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        changedUpdate(e);                       
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        boolean isEnabled = true;
        for(JTextField tf : textFieldList) {
            if(tf.getText().isEmpty())
                isEnabled = false;
        }
        submit.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }
    
};

for(JTextField tf : textFieldList) {
    tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(docListener);
}


final WebDriver newDriver = driver;
final ChromeOptions newOptions = options;

//Click on "SUBMIT" button
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            System.out.println("submitting");
            mainFrame.setVisible(false);
            createTicket(newDriver, newOptions, subportfolio, title, desc , hour, minute, csiID);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {

        }

    }
    
});


//Click on "RESET" button
reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        desc.setText(null);
        hour.setText(null);
        minute.setText(null);
        csiID.setText(null);
    }
    
});
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). In this case it should be simplified to one button and either one (or if the problem doesn't happen with one, two) text field(s). **BTW:** `reqListScroll.setColumnHeaderView(new JLabel("               REQUEST                           CREATED                       TIME WORKED"));` ?? Sounds like this could use a `JTable` instead of the `JTextArea`, but neither component should be in the MRE / SSCCE.

Comment: Yeah I plan on making it a JTable later. Only if I could get the actual button working. Moreover I have a simpler code with 3 text fields and two buttons, and that works totally fine without any focusing issues.

Comment: *"that works totally fine"* So use a subtractive / additive process of changing one code to the other, testing often, and find which part of the difference triggers the error. If you're not able to do that, I doubt anyone else will. But if you truly cannot find out using that process, at least make sure the code posted compiles cleanly without additions (like imports and a `main` method), runs and displays the problem.